# SELECT Row if it has same 2 Fields in 1 table. Else, Select null field instead

Tags: mysql, sql

Would like to select a row if a LOOKUP = COSTID. Else, get the row with the null field instead. Please see table below:
(PAYCODE must be unique)

| PAYCODE | LOOKUP | COSTID | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | null | null | 720001 |
| 201 | 659057 | 659057 | 999999 |
| 202 | null | null | 720002 |
| 202 | 659058 | 659057 | 999999 |

null LOOKUP will be selected for PAYCODE 202 because LOOKUP != COSTID as shown above.

The output must be:

| PAYCODE | LOOKUP | COSTID | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 659057 | 659057 | 999999 |
| 202 | null | null | 720002 |

My SQL so far:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     *
> FROM 
>     gl_table_db t1
> WHERE 
>     LOOKUP = COSTID OR LOOKUP IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gl_table_db t2 WHERE t1.LOOKUP = t2.LOOKUP AND t2.LOOKUP IS NOT NULL
>     AND t1.LOOKUP IS NOT NULL)
> ```

I feel like this is very close but cannot quite get it. Thank you

Comment: What if there's another `PAYCODE=201` row but the `LOOKUP` and `COSTID` is lower/higher value than the one in your example? Maybe `659056` [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79c0addab37a478ddafc55dddc458027)? Which result should the query return?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `ROW_NUMBER` based approach.  We can assign a label of 1 for those records having the same values for `LOOKUP` and `COSTID`.  A value of 0 can be assigned where either `LOOKUP` or `COSTID` be null, and -1 assigned to all other possibilities.  Then, we can retain, for each `PAYCODE`, the record with the highest priority label value.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LOOKUP = COSTID THEN 1
                   WHEN LOOKUP IS NULL OR COSTID IS NULL THEN 0
                   ELSE -1 END AS label
    FROM gl_table_db
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PAYCODE ORDER BY label DESC) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT PAYCODE, LOOKUP, COSTID, ACCOUNT
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close (beware of parenthesis when mixing ANDs and ORs):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    gl_table_db t1
WHERE 
    -- Either we have the not-null version
    t1.LOOKUP = COSTID 
    OR 
    -- OR - if we don't- have the null version
    (t1.LOOKUP IS NULL 
     AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM gl_table_db t2 
                      WHERE t1.PAYCODE = t2.PAYCODE
                        AND t2.LOOKUP=t1.COST_ID
                        )
    )
```